# Why when delete row from table and insert new after this the id is not right?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB and I have a problem with my database table.

First I deleted the row from the table with `id=10`. Now, when I insert new record it is with `id=11` but it must be `id=10`. I set `ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=10`, but when I delete the record and insert new it again saves the deleted id row.

Could someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of an exact fix for this "problem," but it is not really a problem at all, or at least not one for which you should be spending much time worrying.

The contract of an auto increment column is that the auto generated value will always be unique, and that it will tend to increase.  It says nothing about being continuous.  If you need to generate an actual sequence starting from 1, then consider using `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Caution:  `ROW_NUMBER` is available only in the latest of versions.